# webgl earth API basemap control in javascript

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl-earth

Can someone show me the javascript code required to create a layer control to switch basemaps for the webgl earth API, just like at http://www.webglearth.com (the dropdown list)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found a suitable solution, 'cesiumjs', it is javascript based, uses webgl and is open source with very good tutorials and documentation. This project seems excellent and just what I need. Here's a link to the layer control documentation.

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/BaseLayerPicker.html